# Total data length transfered in 802.11 using Wireshark

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11, wireshark

How could I get the total size of a some data that has been transfered using UDP over a wireless channel from a Wireshark capture trace ? I have read somewhere that the sender advertise the total size of data to transmit before sending any actual data. However I could not spot that in my trace.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

UDP is connectionless, i.e. the data consists of distinct UDP datagrams. There's no advertising in UDP itself but it's possible that the application level protocol on top of UDP uses something like that.

If you filter the Wireshark capture for the source IP address and UDP destination port you should get a good idea of the total data transmitted.

Comment: Does TCP advertise the size of data it sends before expecting the **ACK** for that data?

Comment: No. TCP doesn't advertise anything either. For the application/higher layer protocol, TCP is very much like a bidirectional data pipe (socket), similar to a serial connection. Negotiating object sizes and similar is usually only done in the application layer protocol.